# Unable to connect to adb shell via USB

Tags: adb

I have a Karbonn Sparkle V AndroidOve device that was previously getting connected to the adb shell using an USB but after the recent factory restore I am absolutely unable to connect to adb shell. Developer options and debugging using USB are switched on.
The error coming is error: Device not found. 
How can I get it back to connect to Ubuntu adb shell?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138156/discussion-on-question-by-ankit-haldar-unable-to-connect-to-adb-shell-via-usb).